# Evitar que modal se abra al cargar a la página

Tags: bootstrap-4

Tengo una ventana modal que se abre automáticamente al entrar a mi página. ¿Cómo podría evitar esto?
Este es mi código:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Open modal
    </button>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar Registro</h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Desea eliminar el registro seleccionado?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-group-lg mr-2  btn btn-danger btn-baja" href=@Url.Action("Delete", "eq_tblTipoEquipos", new { id = 0 })><span class="far fa-trash-alt"></span> Eliminar</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-group-lg mr-2 btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: has investigado que hace que se active la ventana????

Comment: que version de bootstrap sas usando???

Comment: estoy tratando de investigar pero no eh encontrado un motivo aparente, tal vez alguna funcion de js o jquery que no eh revisado (El proyecto lo use con plantillas ) Estoy usando bootstrap 4

Comment: creo que boostrap tiene una clase hide... para ocultarlo y lugo tendrias que mostrarlo programaticamente estas seguro que leiste la documentancion de modal de bootstrap???

Comment: Estoy basandome de aqui https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp consultare la clase hide que me mencionas

Comment: ese no es el sitio oficial de bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun tus comentarios:

> Estoy basandome de aqui w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp

Deberías de implementar el ejemplo del sitio oficial y utilizar un botón para desplegar el modal o un evento.

no me fio de ejemplos de terceros. intenta con los siguientes ejemplos que ya he validado que funcionan correctamente aquí.

*según la documentación de Bootstrap para 5.1:* [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-PsUw7Xwds7x08Ew3exXhqzbhuEYmA2xnwc8BuD6SEr+UmEHlX8/MCltYEodzWA4u" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

*según la documentación de Bootstrap para 4.6:* [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte Francisco Núñez-Todo Poderoso me fue de gran utilidad

Comment: @user252138 si resolví tu pregunta pudes marcarla resuelta...

Comment: El atributo [`aria-hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute) no muestra ni oculta un modal de BS en pantalla, lo hace únicamente para las tecnologías de asistencia o accesibilidad, basándose en el [estándar WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/aria/). No entiendo cómo el OP logró solucionar su error agregando únicamente ese atributo.

Comment: No, BS4 no lo resuelve, tu acabas de mandarme los mismos enlaces que te vinculé, crea un [example] de tu respuesta, con y sin el atributo aria-hidden, y verás que no afecta visualmente el modal. Únicamente oculta su contenido para, por ej, lectores de pantalla. Una vez el modal es cargado y visualizado en el DOM, el lector entiende el cambio de aria-hidden="false"  y "lee" el contenido del modal.

Comment: "Agregar aria-hidden='true' a un elemento elimina ese elemento y todos sus elementos secundarios **del árbol de accesibilidad**. Esto puede mejorar la experiencia de los **usuarios de tecnología de asistencia** al ocultar..." Mira este ejemplo, independientemente de su atributo, abre y cierra sin problema. https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/KKvPzVa

Comment: vuelvo y repito: supongo que el uso correcto del ejemplo de bs4 lo resuelve ...